# Count the number of whitespace in the beginning of a line

Tags: indentation, counting

How to count the number of whitespace in the beginning of a line ( aka indentation ).
eg:

```
foo()
    foo()
```

And then

```
:command(2)
4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

so easy i'm ashamed.

```
:echo indent(2)
```

Comment: And you can use `:echo indent('.') / &shiftwidth` to get the indent width of the current line (that's what `.` refers to) divided by the `shiftwidth` to get the indentation level.